# How to purge historical bind variable information from data dictionary

Tags: oracle

I am using oracle database 19c. I need to delete the historical bind variable information from memory either automatically or manually. Is there anyway to purge the bind variables from memory? I set the value for parameter `cursor_bind_capture_destination` as memory.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with details of: the client application where you define the bind variable; the data type of the bind variable; and what you mean by "bind variable information"?

Comment: Bind variable information used by SQL cursors which are captured in v$sql_bind_capture(memory) or DBA_HIST_SQLBIND (disk) for all SQL in general.  There are no specific datatypes. What test case is required for purging bind variable?

Comment: Are you asking how to purge the bind variable from being re-used on the client application? Or about purging the history associated with the bind variable from the data dictionary on the Oracle database?

Comment: Purge historical bind variable from data dictionary in memory

Comment: **DO NOT**. If you edit the data dictionary then you risk leaving the database in an inconsistent state and crashing the database.

Comment: I dont  mean to edit the data dictionary objects. I ask if there are any standard way to purge the bind objects similar to AWR snapshot purge.

Comment: What business problem do you think is being solved by this supposed purge?

Comment: There is no business problem. Does this question need a justification to answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove SQL bind data with `ALTER SYSTEM FLUSH SHARED_POOL` and `DBMS_WORKLOAD_REPOSITORY.DROP_SNAPSHOT_RANGE`. But keep in mind that flushing the shared pool may cause temporary performance problems, and dropping the snapshots will remove lots of historical performance data. Unless you have some sensitive data in the bind variables that you need to immediately remove, like a password, it's probably better to just let the information slowly age out.

Note that the keyword `FLUSH` is a bit misleading - the `ALTER SYSTEM FLUSH SHARED_POOL` command just removes the bind data from memory but does not write it to `DBA_HIST_SQLBIND`.

### Remove From Memory

```
--4580 rows in memory before.
select count(*) from v$sql_bind_capture;

--Remove SQL statements and related data like bind variables from memory.
--(Unless the SQL is actively in use, then it does not get flushed.)
--Be careful running this on a production database, as it may cause temporary performance
--issues while Oracle has to rebuild performance metadata.
alter system flush shared_pool;

--214 rows in memory after.
select count(*) from v$sql_bind_capture;
```

### Remove From Disk

```
--32052 rows in AWR before.
select count(*) from dba_hist_sqlbind;

--Remove SQL statement metadata from AWR.
--If you're using a multitenant database, you may have to run this on the CDB.
declare
    v_min_snap number;
    v_max_snap number;
begin
    select min(snap_id), max(snap_id)
    into v_min_snap, v_max_snap
    from dba_hist_snapshot
    where dbid = sys_context('userenv', 'dbid');

    dbms_workload_repository.drop_snapshot_range
    (
        low_snap_id  => v_min_snap,
        high_snap_id => v_max_snap
    );
end;
/

--232 rows in AWR after.
select count(*) from dba_hist_sqlbind;
```

Comment: I am confused if cursor_bind_capture_destination value set as 'memory', flush bind data to dba_hist_sqlbind. Could you please elaborate on this?

Comment: @Kishan I updated my answer a bit. FLUSH just removes data and doesn't write it to disk.

Comment: but flushing shared pool flushes other cached objects apart from binds right ? Is there any way to purge only cached binds?

Comment: @Kishan You're right, the shared pool flush will remove lots of cached objects. As far as I know, there is no way to purge only cached binds. However, if you're only interested in removing cached binds for a specific SQL, you can flush just those cursors with `DBMS_SHARED_POOL.PURGE`.